# Magento 2.3.6-p1 Installation Incomplete and showing errors in Magento_Theme while installing

Tags: windows, xampp, magento2, magento-2.3, magento-installation

When i am trying to install magento 2.3.6 on xampp server in windows then i am getting errors in magento Module which is Magento_Theme and error is about Invalid Argument Exception and saying Wrong file in
/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php with this messafe 64 stack trace: 0.

[Full Image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeIra.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have searched in google for this answer and then I got an answer.

I have replaced a function on line no 86.
vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php

```
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
{
    $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
    $url = parse_url($filename);
    if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Replaced With the below function

```
    private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
      {
          $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
          $url = parse_url($filename);
          if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !file_exists($filename)) {
              return false;
          }

          return true;
      }
      }
```

[After Change the code successful installation complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Ra7.png)